# UML Designer, how to generate Java classes from UML Diagram

Tags: uml-designer

I am using Obeo UML Designer v. 8.0.0 (latest version downloaded from [here](http://obeo-umldesigner-nightly.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/master/bundles/UMLDesigner-win32.win32.x86_64.zip)), to design an UML data model, and I would like to generate the Java classes corresponding to the model. How can I generate the classes?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the 8.0.0 is still in beta status, you downloaded a nightly version. The generation is a new feature in UML Designer. At the moment I know that we have a packaging issue and so the generation menus are not visible. This will be fixed soon and before the official 8.0.0 release in july.

Comment: Thanks, UML Designer is really a great open source tool for UML Design, and I look forward to using the new features.